# Can anyone explain me how to make android app which can fit on most of devices screens?I did not understand any thing from documentation

Tags: android, user-interface, screen

When I try to make some android app then it seems very good for some devices but on some other devices(mostly which have a lower android API version) it does not look so much better. Sometimes some view (like button)goes out of the screen size.
I have read the documentation provided by Google.But I did not understand anything.As I am a new learner so it is creating many problems for me. If anyone has some time then please help me to understand this thing in the easiest way.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide some exact issues?

Comment: Have you learned to use ConstrainLayout, LinearLayout or FrameLayout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please go through this https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

For layouts define additional smallest width layouts:

res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)

res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)

res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)

res/layout-sw600dp-land/main_activity.xml # layout for landscape mode.

For example, see below pic

[image]

Comment: Are we also required to create different values folders having(strings.xml,dimens.xml, colors.xml) or only dimens is required??

Answer (score 3):

most of the time i uses ssp and sdp. The ssp a scalable size unit for texts is android SDK that provides a new size unit - ssp (scalable sp). This size unit scales with the screen size based on the sp size unit (for texts). It can help Android developers with supporting multiple screens.and sdp This is the sibling of the sdp size unit that should be used for non text views. 
 [https://github.com/intuit/ssp][1] and [https://github.com/intuit/sdp][1]
 use gradle and compile libraries like below

```
compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.4'
```

in your layout activity xml  for example for text you can provide like this

```
android:textSize="@dimen/_16ssp"
```

for layouts

```
android:layout_height="@dimen/_16sdp"
```

this will take care for any screens enjoy.